# Proper style of do binding in F#

Tags: .net, f#

One of the more subtle uses of the 'do' keyword in F# is the ability to annotate expressions that return unit (aka statements). For example I often do this in function definitions to make it clear that the return type is unit and also instruct the compiler to type check this for me. For example:

```
let restart agent = do agent.Post Restart
```

However I am unsure what the dominant take on the 'do' keyword is in the F# community.

What's the proper way to use the 'do' keyword in this example:

```
// Annotate each statement
let move source destination =
    do copy source destination
    do clear source

// Annotate the statements as one block
let move source destination =
    do
        copy source destination
        clear source

// Just annotate the "return" statement
let move source destination =
    copy source destination
    do clear source

// Perhaps don't annotate at all?
let move source destination =
    copy source destination
    clear source
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I seldom see `do` used in F# code for this purpose (introducing `unit` expressions). Most of the typechecking you describe is already automatically performed without it, in the form of the FS0020 warning about unused values.

If you simply write

```
let move source destination =
    copy source destination
    clear source
```

then one of three things will happen:

- Both `copy` and `clear` return `unit`

  In this case all is well.
- `copy` returns a type other than unit

  In this case you will receive the FS0020 warning about an ignored value:

  > The expression `copy source destination` returns an int which is currently being ignored. If you do not require this value, you should explicitly ignore it using the ignore function e.g. `ignore (copy source destination)` or bind the result to a name e.g. `let result = copy source destination`
- `copy` returns unit, `clear` returns a type other than `unit`

  In this case there will be no warning, but `move` will have the same type as `clear`, and this discrepancy will manifest at the call site for `move`, where you will get the same warning as above.

So the utility of `do` for typechecking purposes is fairly limited: only in the last case it will make a difference, by making the warning appear at the original line instead of forcing you to navigate to it from `move`'s call site (or potentially - if `move` is the last line in its scope - from `move`'s caller's call site, and so forth). And that will rarely be an error in the first place - if `clear` returns a value (e.g. a boolean indicating whether the clearing succeeded), you definitely *do* want to propagate that information up the calling chain!

That said, it's a very simple token that (IMO) doesn't harm readability in the slightest, and arguably improves it. Considering that the F# community has no problem with a minority of users who prefer to disable the light syntax (`#light "off"`) and manually type out semicolons and `end` tokens, I can't imagine `do` raising any eyebrows anywhere.

Comment: Great answer! I'm aware of FS0020, but I prefer to be explicit in this case, especially since unit expression implies side effects, forcing you to think about each such usage and also drawing the eyes of a reader to it. Speaking of semicolons, another option could be: do copy source destination; clear source